# Duplicate symbols with global template variable using Clang

Tags: c++, templates, clang, compiler-bug

I have these three files

```cpp
// foo.h
#pragma once

template <typename T> const T foo;

template <>
const int foo<int> = 1;
```

```cpp
// a.cpp
#include "foo.h"

int main() {}
```

```cpp
// b.cpp
#include "foo.h"
```

If I build these with GCC 7.5.0 on Linux it works fine:

```sh
$ g++ -std=c++17 a.cpp b.cpp -o out
$
```

However with Apple Clang 12.0.0 on Mac it gives this error:

```sh
$ clang++ -std=c++17 a.cpp b.cpp -o out
duplicate symbol 'foo<int>' in:
    /var/folders/g5/8twmk1xj481_6btvppyw5j4h0000gp/T/a-62bdde.o
    /var/folders/g5/8twmk1xj481_6btvppyw5j4h0000gp/T/b-ea4997.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

Should this be an error, or is it a bug in Clang?

Answer (score 3):

RedFrog's answer is correct - this violates the One Definition Rule (ODR) but it doesn't really explain *why* it violates the ODR. In C++ global `const` variables have internal (`static`) linkage, which should result in a separate instance of the variable for each compilation unit, so ODR isn't violated. However [it turns out](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) that `const` does not cause *template* variables to have internal linkage:

> The const qualifier used on a declaration of a non-local non-volatile non-template (since C++14) non-inline (since C++17) variable that is not declared extern gives it internal linkage.

There are a few ways to fix this.

### Internal Linkage using `static`

You can use `static` on template variables to [gives them internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage):

> Any of the following names declared at namespace scope have internal linkage:
>
> variables, variable templates (since C++14), functions, or function templates declared static;

Edit: I don't recommend using this technique. If you apply `static` to the declaration and the specialisations then it works fine in Clang but GCC (as of now at least) complains that

```
error: explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class
```

If you set `static` only on the declaration, then it compiles in GCC but you get duplicate symbol errors with Clang.

### Internal Linkage using `namespace`

Putting template variables in an anonymous namespace also gives them internal linkage.

> In addition, all names declared in unnamed namespace or a namespace within an unnamed namespace, even ones explicitly declared extern, have internal linkage.

### Disable ODR using `inline`

This is a bit different. Template variables that are declared `inline` but not `static` still have external linkage, but [are allowed to have more than one definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).

> An inline function or variable (since C++17) with external linkage (e.g. not declared static) has the following additional properties:
>
> - There may be more than one definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit and (for non-static inline functions and variables (since C++17)) all definitions are identical. For example, an inline function or an inline variable (since C++17) may be defined in a header file that is #include'd in multiple source files.
> - It must be declared inline in every translation unit.
> - It has the same address in every translation unit.

This means that `inline` for variables behaves like `inline` for functions.

If in doubt, `inline` is probably the best option to go for. In the very simple tests I've done they all produced identical output, even at -O0, but in theory `inline` guarantees that there is only one copy of the variable in your program because it still has external linkage, whereas the other methods don't. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

it violates [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), and should be `inline` (since C++17).

why it violates ODR:

> One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined.

because `foo.h` is included by both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`, the variable `foo<int>` is defined in each translation unit, `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`. so it has 2 definitions in this program, which violates the former rule, except if it's unused (it means, not *ODR-used*) or it's an `inline` variable.

you have 2 solutions:

1. put `template<> int const foo<int> = 1;` into another `foo.cpp`. and then it will have only one definition.
2. add `inline` (since C++17) for `foo`. an `inline` variable is allowed to have more than one **same** definitions among translation units.

Comment: @TedLyngmo okay, I will use terms of *cppreference*: *since C++17*.

Comment: Can you be more specific? That's a very long page!

Comment: @Timmmm I edited my answer, and explained why your code violated ODR. but it's just for your code, if you want to know more about how it works, read that page of *cppreference* again, I suggest.

Comment: So why is `const int bar = 1;` ok? (An anonymous namespace worked btw, just trying to understand this.)

Comment: @Timmmm You obviously have question related to your first one. Make it a proper question.

Comment: @Timmmm if you declare a `const` variable at the top scope, which is initialized by a constant expression, it will be thought as a compile-time constant. in this case, use the **value** of it is not an ODR-used (that means, for example, `&bar` or `int const& ref = bar` is still an ODR-used), and then it actually has no definition in this program. we always use `constexpr` instead of `const` to mark it explicitly (but `const` is still allowed, because that's the only way until C++11).

Comment: @RedFog: `const int some_global = 1;` is allowed because `const` variables automatically have internal (`static`) linkage. The question is why does that not happen for const template variables?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: No, my question is still the original one. I don't think the answer has been fully explained yet. It is normal to ask for clarifications in comments on StackOverflow, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

As given, this is indeed an ODR violation as stated in the other answers, but the point here should be that this is a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96523).  [basic.link]/3.2 gives **internal** linkage to a “non-template variable of non-volatile const-qualified type”, but GCC is giving `foo` internal linkage despite it being a variable **template**.  (Here, we could rationalize it as a consequence of there being no diagnostic required, but the bug can be observed by a well-formed program by comparing the address of an implicitly instantiated specialization in two different translation units.)