# clang creates global symbols; gcc creates local symbols

Tags: c++, c++17, one-definition-rule

I'm  porting a program from gcc to clang, and ran into a strange difference  in behavior:

```
enum struct E : unsigned  char {
    zero  =  0,
    one   =  1,
    two   =  2,
    three =  3,
    answ  = 42,
};

template<E> constexpr int doubler =  -1;

template<> constexpr int doubler<E::zero>  =  0;
template<> constexpr int doubler<E::one>   =  2;
template<> constexpr int doubler<E::two>   =  4;
template<> constexpr int doubler<E::three> =  6;
template<> constexpr int doubler<E::answ>  = 84;
```

After compiling this code with various compilers (packaged compilers in WSL Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS), I  got slightly different object files from gcc and clang:

```
$ for c  in g++     g++-10  g++-8   g++-9 clang++-10  clang++-12 ; do $c -c -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -std=c++17 meow.cpp -o meow-$c.o ; done
$ nm -C *.o

meow-clang++-10.o:
0000000000000000 R doubler<(E)0>
0000000000000004 R doubler<(E)1>
0000000000000008 R doubler<(E)2>
000000000000000c R doubler<(E)3>
0000000000000010 R doubler<(E)42>

meow-clang++-12.o:
0000000000000000 R doubler<(E)0>
0000000000000004 R doubler<(E)1>
0000000000000008 R doubler<(E)2>
000000000000000c R doubler<(E)3>
0000000000000010 R doubler<(E)42>

meow-g++-10.o:
0000000000000000 r doubler<(E)0>
0000000000000004 r doubler<(E)1>
0000000000000008 r doubler<(E)2>
000000000000000c r doubler<(E)3>
0000000000000010 r doubler<(E)42>

meow-g++-8.o:
0000000000000000 r doubler<(E)0>
0000000000000004 r doubler<(E)1>
0000000000000008 r doubler<(E)2>
000000000000000c r doubler<(E)3>
0000000000000010 r doubler<(E)42>

meow-g++-9.o:
0000000000000000 r doubler<(E)0>
0000000000000004 r doubler<(E)1>
0000000000000008 r doubler<(E)2>
000000000000000c r doubler<(E)3>
0000000000000010 r doubler<(E)42>

meow-g++.o:
0000000000000000 r doubler<(E)0>
0000000000000004 r doubler<(E)1>
0000000000000008 r doubler<(E)2>
000000000000000c r doubler<(E)3>
0000000000000010 r doubler<(E)42>
$ readelf -s meow*.o | egrep 'File|doubler' | c++filt
File: meow-clang++-10.o
     2: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)0>
     3: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)1>
     4: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)2>
     5: 000000000000000c     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)3>
     6: 0000000000000010     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)42>
File: meow-clang++-12.o
     2: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)0>
     3: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)1>
     4: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)2>
     5: 000000000000000c     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)3>
     6: 0000000000000010     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 doubler<(E)42>
File: meow-g++-10.o
     6: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)0>
     7: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)1>
     8: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)2>
     9: 000000000000000c     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)3>
    10: 0000000000000010     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)42>
File: meow-g++-8.o
     6: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)0>
     7: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)1>
     8: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)2>
     9: 000000000000000c     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)3>
    10: 0000000000000010     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)42>
File: meow-g++-9.o
     6: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)0>
     7: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)1>
     8: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)2>
     9: 000000000000000c     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)3>
    10: 0000000000000010     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)42>
File: meow-g++.o
     6: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)0>
     7: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)1>
     8: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)2>
     9: 000000000000000c     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)3>
    10: 0000000000000010     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 doubler<(E)42>
```

Why does clang create symbols with GLOBAL binding, when gcc creates symbols with LOCAL binding?

There doesn't seem to be a significant difference in the assembly generated by gcc  and clang (https://godbolt.org/z/K8fcaWMT7), so why the difference in the symbols in the object files? Is this a difference between `llvm-as` and `gas`?

How can I make clang create symbols with LOCAL binding?

In real life, these variables are defined in a header, so my situation is similar to [Duplicate symbols with global template variable using Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610024/duplicate-symbols-with-global-template-variable-using-clang) . The header is included from multiple translation units, so the program violates the One Definition Rule. GCC compiles  and  links the program, but linking objects compiled with clang fails with multiple definitions of these symbols.

Unfortunately, the header is not under  my control (the proper fix would be to get rid of the ODR  violation using `inline` or an unnamed namespace), so it would be useful  if at least I could get the program to link until the header is fixed.

Comment: You should edit your question to restrict it to “How can I work around this without changing the header?”, since the rest of it is a duplicate of the very question you linked.

Comment: Yes and no. I really want to understand why the symbols are different when compiling the example program, and there's no ODR violation there.

Comment: Your “real life” case does contain the violation, and my (new) answer there explains why GCC uses local symbols that hide it.

Comment: You should turn your comment into an  answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: If that’s the answer (*i.e.*, you don’t care about the workaround idea), this is a duplicate.